# Is it possible to launch the Scenario Manager using a VBA macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a MIS (Management Information System) in Excel, and am required to make use of 'What-If Analysis'.

I'm in the process of adding various scenarios to the Scenario Manager, and to make it more user-friendly I am displaying the whole system in full-screen. This however means that the user won't be able to open the Scenario Manager.

I cannot simply assign each scenario to a button/drop-down list as the user needs to have the ability to edit each scenario. This therefore means that I'll need to program a VBA macro to launch the Scenario Manager.

This, however, has presented a problem: *it doesn't seem possible to launch the Scenario Manager using VBA!*

I've tried searching for it, but however all pages I've visited contain code for launching an individual scenario with the following:

```
ActiveSheet.Scenarios("[scenario name here]").Show
```

However there doesn't seem to be anything to launch the actual scenario manager:

[image]

I've also attempted to record a macro to do this, but the macro itself is empty:

```
Sub whatIfManager()
'
' whatIfManager Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+W
'
End Sub
```

I tried `ActiveSheet.Scenarios().Show` on the off-chance that would work, but it doesn't (no method with that name).

Is it possible at all to launch the what-if scenario manager using VBA? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are looking for is in the `Application` object, specifically [`Application.Dialogs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193689.aspx). Something like this will do it:

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogScenarioCells).Show
```

The enumeration value determines the dialog to show. The full list of dialogs is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194519.aspx).